# QPainter/Python - Graphic display issue

Tags: pyqt, qpainter

I am tackling some Tutorials on Qt. I have ran the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        self.draw_something()
        
    def draw_something(self):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)
        painter.end()
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

However, when I ran the code, instead of a single black line on the canvas running diagonally, I have this:

[image]

"Normal" GUI without QPainter - that is, using plain simple QWidgets - work fine. Kernel restart does not change the issue.

Any suggestion on how to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap): "Warning: This will create a QPixmap with uninitialized data. Call fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing onto it with QPainter." Use `canvas.fill(Qt.white)` (or any color you need, including `Qt.transparent`).

Comment: @musicamante, that did the trick! Thanks.